# Basic Set Theory Definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I've just started reading a set theory book, and I've got a small question.

The book defines $A - B = \left\{ {x | x \in A, x \not \in B}\right\}$ and my question is simply whether that definition is the same as saying $A - B = \left\{ {x \in A | x \not \in B}\right\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.
The second simply takes the first condition of x and makes it an initial requirement.